# How to import OpenPGP key given the key ID in GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, import, public-key

I'm having a heck of a time installing a Debian Chroot for PPC64. The problem is *not* `debootstrap`, rather, its getting GnuPG to locate and install the key I need.

The [man pages for `gpg` are fairly useless](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html), but that's no surprise. Searching is equally frustrating, which is leading me to believe I can't perform the simple task because GnuPG does not support it ([it would not be the first time](https://superuser.com/q/884805/173513)).

Here's what I have tried:

```
# gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.19
# gpg --import 75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1
gpg: can't open `75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1': No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0
# gpg --import --key 75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1
gpg: Option "--key" is ambiguous
# gpg --import --keyid 75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1
gpg: unknown keyid-format `75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1'
```

How do I instruct GnuPG to fetch and install a key based on the key ID?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong option.

`--import` is used if you want to import the key from a file.

`--recv-keys` will fetch your keys from a keyserver.

Comment: What about importing keys with the key ID?

Answer (score 1):

You might actually be suffering from two issues at the same time.

### Importing Keys

`gpg --import [file]` loads key information from a file or stdin, but does not query key servers for the key. `gpg --recv-keys` does some additional things: it queries a key server (preconfigured in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` or passed with `--keyserver`), fetches the result (internally, these two steps are usually implemented as an HTTP request) and *finally* imports the key.

### apt-key

I'm also not sure whether you need that key in your personal GnuPG home directory, or whether you want to install software from third party repositories using `apt-get`. In this case, don't directly run something like

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv [key-id]
```

to store the key into apt's "private" keyring (`apt-key` is a kind of wrapper around GnuPG, for example taking care of storing into the correct keyring). apt does *not* query your normal user's GnuPG keyring!